# Make text and select input type to be of same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the height  of input elements to be of same size in BS3

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 pull-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4  pull-right">
                <select  class="form-control" placeholder="Role" />
            </div>
</div>
```

As per [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes), I should be on right track, however the `text` elements are smaller than the `select` element

UPDATE1:
[image: A picture may help]

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The `<input/>` and `<select></select>` elements both use the same class `form-control`, which make them adapt to the width of their *parent* element, in this case `col-xs-4`. If you look at this example http://www.bootply.com/0ZHyKCc2KX you can see they are exactly the same width, as their parent elements have the same width. Try to better explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: @TimLewis: Updated my question - how would i get them to be of same height

Comment: Ok, but they currently are the same height... http://www.bootply.com/EkCQ5lt64f You can adjust it by adding `form-control input-*`, where `*` can be `sm` or `lg`, but I really have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: @TimLewis: I ran your bootply and they are of same dimension. When i run it on my sample html page, the `text` element is shorter in height than the `select`

Comment: Then there might be some CSS on your page that is overriding the height of either of these elements. Can you create an exact replica of your sample html page in Bootply or JSFiddle? That way we can see what the precise issue it.

Comment: @TimLewis: I added a picture, it is a bare bone text project page. The city and state elements do not appear to be of same height.

Comment: I can see that, but a picture doesn't help... How can I debug your question from a picture... I think you're missing the `form-control` class on your `<input type="text">` elements, but I can't tell that from a picture.

Comment: @TimLewis: You pointed me in right direction. The css file i was given was overriding the default BS3 css and once i removed the company css, things work as expected. Many thanks. How do i mark your suggestion as answer, as you put it in comments?

Comment: I can add a quick answer. Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that any subsequent `.css` files included *after* `bootstrap.css` may override the functionality of certain core aspects. For example:

```
.form-control{ 
    height: 20px;
}
```

Including something like this will override the matching `css` applied from Bootstrap. If you are having an issue, always verify that the issue can be reproduced in a standardized sand-box environment, such as Bootply or JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

i do not recommend to manipulate height. Let them grow to the size they need. But 1 solution is using css height or max-height attribute like

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 pull-left">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User" style="height:50px" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4  pull-right">
            <select  class="form-control" placeholder="Role"  style="height:50px" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is specific to Chrome and IE. Firefox displays select and input elements as expected.

One solution to resolve the adjacent misaligned col-* is:

```
<style>
input{
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
select{
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
</style>
```

which will cause all three browsers to display these elements as if they are on the same "bootstrap rows/ columns", though the input and select elements will still be different heights.

---

Or you can follow the [Bootstrap recommendations](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example) as indicated by Tim Lewis and add:

```
class:"form-group"
```

to the col-* or containing elements 
and:

```
class:"form-control"
```

to the input/ select elements.

(though the class:"form-control" is all you need to ensure consistent element heights)

```
Basic example
Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling. 
All textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select> elements with .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default. 
Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.
```

---

Personally, I think the default form-control class is too big and even adding both form-control and input-sm, as alluded to in the comments, is too large for my tastes. My recommendation is to add the form-control class and add/ define an input-xs class as so:

```
<style>
.input-xs {
    height: 23px;   
    padding: 2px 4px;  
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
```

---

The above differences are most likely due to the way the different browsers render the dropdown arrow for the select elements.
Chrome:

```
internal line-height:
input: 18px
select: 19px

computed:
input: 22px
select: 21px

due to:
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type]), input[type="email" i], input[type="number" i], input[type="password" i], input[type="tel" i], input[type="url" i], input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
```

IE is a little more opaque as to which attributes are used to compute the final size (it doesn't display the user style-sheet styles, as Chrome does):

```
In IE the internal Line-Heights of each element are the same:
internal line-height for both elements: 18.57px;

but if you look at the computed Layout it shows
input: 22.57px
select: 21.29px
```

Firefox displays the elements correctly, though. I assume because it rounds 22.5667px up to 23px.

```
Firefox:
internal line-height:
input: 18.5667px
select: 21px

computed:
input: 22.5667px
select: 23px
```